# volume of solid of rotation: finding r

Tags: calculus, integration, rotations

For a region bounded by:
$$y=x+4,\;y=16-x^2;\;around\;y=-5$$
I understand that I will be using the 'washer' method:
$$V =\int_a^b\pi r^2h$$
But I'm having a hard time finding  $$r^2 \text{ for}= \pi(r_{out}^2 -r_{in}^2)dx$$

Since the axis of rotation is at $y=-5$ and the higest point is at 16...

is r:
$$(r_{out}^2 -r_{in}^2) \Rightarrow \bigg(11-(16-x^2)\bigg)^2 - \bigg(11-(16-x^2)\bigg)^2?$$

Comment: What is $h$ in this case?

Comment: @Vladhagen $h$ would be $dx$ in this particular case

Comment: So it is like the thickness of the disk/waher

Comment: @Vladhagen That is correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your inner curve is going to be $x+4$ and your outer curve is going to be $16-x^2$. So the radii are : $r_{in} = x+4 + 5 = x+9$ and $r_{out} = 16-x^2 + 5 = 21-x^2$.

Note that this comes from the fact that our inner curve is $y=x+4$. So our total inner radius is going to be $y + 5$, which includes both the distance above the $x$-axis and the distance below the $x$-axis. A similar argument explains the our radius.

See that one of the intersections of the curves is at $x=-4$. So that gives us our lower bound of the integral. I will let you attempt to solve for the upper bound.

Comment: so the radius is calculated from the axis of rotation to the closest point of the region?  in this case, it's $y=0$, but if it was $y=1$ the radii would be $6 + \text{curve}_{top}$, $6 + \text{curve}_{bot}$?

Comment: The curve will always give you part of your radius, then any further distance that you have to cover is added on. If our curves were both shifted up 1 unit, you would still just use the curves plus 5. Think of it like a wooden board. You cut it into 2 pieces; The part above the $x$-axis and the part below the $x$-axis. Add the two parts together to get one whole.

Comment: The closest point to the $x$-axis will usually not really matter.